# key error while parsing python dictionary

Tags: python, json, api, youtube-data-api

```
{
"kind": "youtube#commentThreadListResponse",
"etag": "5b1YCNidguUpH4QsR6mpPJrL6es",
"nextPageToken": "QURTSl9pMTQwTEZFU1VRZTB1R2toTFh5djJJSWQzM1oyOXp4Z3ppSXZSNEtNQ25RRzQyRm1xXzFwMDZvc3dqb1g5dnQyTnVUMVJld2lWVXFta2tFclh2LWk3eENwOFFxMmluTGhlY3JXOHNsSnh4ZlFyNllfdWVWMVlPdkhiWWlnVzA=",
"pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 100,
    "resultsPerPage": 100
},
"items": [
    {
        "kind": "youtube#commentThread",
        "etag": "GQifP0HFLluusa1n0pFQCxggSvI",
        "id": "UgxWDLFO6d6fhe4UaJd4AaABAg",
        "snippet": {
            "videoId": "BEWz4SXfyCQ",
            "topLevelComment": {
                "kind": "youtube#comment",
                "etag": "YlbdyUbeN1LqFBOqDnQnQZU2DnQ",
                "id": "UgxWDLFO6d6fhe4UaJd4AaABAg",
                "snippet": {
                    "videoId": "BEWz4SXfyCQ",
                    "textDisplay": "Honestly Jeremy is just an annoying piggyback rider",
                    "textOriginal": "Honestly Jeremy is just an annoying piggyback rider",
                    "authorDisplayName": "Michael Myers",
                    "authorProfileImageUrl": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AATXAJwHIfrPXguIZR7YggVntreixLfBisGtlo5xTg=s48-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo",
                    "authorChannelUrl": "http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCs4do_iNqxBcxxPmv6U1VPg",
                    "authorChannelId": {
                        "value": "UCs4do_iNqxBcxxPmv6U1VPg"
                    },
                    "canRate": true,
                    "viewerRating": "none",
                    "likeCount": 0,
                    "publishedAt": "2020-07-08T20:55:48Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2020-07-08T20:55:48Z"
                }
            },
            "canReply": true,
            "totalReplyCount": 0,
            "isPublic": true
        }
    },

    {
        "kind": "youtube#commentThread",
        "etag": "wFEgumlYzFR2ZLOsHgEdQoV45SI",
        "id": "UgxaQ38-nL84EgK9ABh4AaABAg",
        "snippet": {
            "videoId": "BEWz4SXfyCQ",
            "topLevelComment": {
                "kind": "youtube#comment",
                "etag": "KyMK87Zq9ej2AHtl44x5-ykwnzQ",
                "id": "UgxaQ38-nL84EgK9ABh4AaABAg",
                "snippet": {
                    "videoId": "BEWz4SXfyCQ",
                    "textDisplay": "Bring bob back and leave captain graybeard at the damn house",
                    "textOriginal": "Bring bob back and leave captain graybeard at the damn house",
                    "authorDisplayName": "Brad Johnson",
                    "authorProfileImageUrl": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AATXAJzzXxTu9bz5hzGL20X1w3ALIcqIWBCc4uzuQPS8=s48-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo",
                    "authorChannelUrl": "http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCwTUCnELUJ3IwcBsEwqjNaQ",
                    "authorChannelId": {
                        "value": "UCwTUCnELUJ3IwcBsEwqjNaQ"
                    },
                    "canRate": true,
                    "viewerRating": "none",
                    "likeCount": 1,
                    "publishedAt": "2020-07-08T18:37:35Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2020-07-08T18:37:35Z"
                }
            },
            "canReply": true,
            "totalReplyCount": 1,
            "isPublic": true
        },
        "replies": {
            "comments": [
                {
                    "kind": "youtube#comment",
                    "etag": "eEq9MZRmGGq3sX4IpzEHk_pYvTw",
                    "id": "UgxaQ38-nL84EgK9ABh4AaABAg.9ArZ6N2FniS9ArdOylLUcm",
                    "snippet": {
                        "videoId": "BEWz4SXfyCQ",
                        "textDisplay": "No, because then there'd be no one to distract you from what a fraud Lazar is.",
                        "textOriginal": "No, because then there'd be no one to distract you from what a fraud Lazar is.",
                        "parentId": "UgxaQ38-nL84EgK9ABh4AaABAg",
                        "authorDisplayName": "Rombert Dillahuntsvalle",
                        "authorProfileImageUrl": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AATXAJwALDysFZlmZoXLVeqzSZc6HcvUetsOCk6a2vTY=s48-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo",
                        "authorChannelUrl": "http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCpdQrMvl72DIMs1vpsKvpgQ",
                        "authorChannelId": {
                            "value": "UCpdQrMvl72DIMs1vpsKvpgQ"
                        },
                        "canRate": true,
                        "viewerRating": "none",
                        "likeCount": 0,
                        "publishedAt": "2020-07-08T19:23:49Z",
                        "updatedAt": "2020-07-08T19:23:49Z"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
```

The code is:

```
for i in data['items']:
    print (i['replies']['comments'][0]['snippet']['textOriginal'])
```

My apologies for the terrible formatting, but I couldn't get all of it to fit in the code block.

I am trying to retrieve the nested "replies" then "comments". I have searched extensively through similar posts, and am still stuck.

I keep getting a key error for 'replies'.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: There isn't any 'replies' key in the first element in the data['items'] list.  Thus the error.  You have a 'replies' key in the 2nd element of the data['items'] list.

Comment: You can check if `replies` exists in the `dict`. `for i in data['items']: if 'replies' in i: print (i['replies']['comments'][0]['snippet']['textOriginal'])`

Comment: @ewong right, so would I use a '[2]' for that instead? to select the second element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need either to check if the key exists or use a `try/except` block:

```
for i in dct['items']:
    try:
        print(i['replies']['comments'][0]['snippet']['textOriginal'])
    except KeyError:
        pass
```

This yields for your given input:

```
No, because then there'd be no one to distract you from what a fraud Lazar is.
```